# The layout on Android Emulator doesn't look like the layout I've made in Android Application Project

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

The layout on Android Emulator doesn't look like the layout I've made in Android Application Project.

I have made a layout in eclipse with two radiobuttons and two spinners, but when I run it on Android emulator the spinners get two extra radiobutton each beside the arrow sign. (Please see the images below). Moreover when I run it on my Android Phone, all four radiobuttons become black. I can't take a snapshot of the app on my Android phone while running it at the same time but the buttons become black. My project is running Android version 4.1.2 in eclipse and my smartphone has the same version as well. Any tip would be valuable for me, thank you.

P.S: When I have only this class in a separate project, no extra radiobutton comes in the spinner. It's only when I am calling this class from a method of another class in a bigger project.

[image: layout in eclipse]

[image: layout in emulator]

Comment: change the theme to light .. may be that could help. Also always test on the device.

Comment: the theme is actually light for every class in manifest but still, on the device all radio buttons become black ://

Comment: try cleaning the project

Comment: Cleaning didnt help :/ Its a really rare case. Never happened anything like this before.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably because the API you are using on android studio is different than the one you're using on your emulator. Change the API you're viewing on Android Studio and then edit it.