# How to add items into a ListView from a List of another class

Tags: android, listview

How can I add items from another class to my listview in mainactivity class I really dont know. Any tips will be really valuable. :((((

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private ListView listOfTweets;
private ArrayAdapter<String> tweetsAdapter;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listOfTweets = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.simple_list_item_1);
    listOfTweets.setAdapter(tweetsAdapter);
    TweetUtil tu = new TweetUtil();
   //How to get list of tweets from TweetUtil here and add it in my listView here ?? ://

}
}
```

This is the TweetUtil class.

```
public class TweetUtil{
    public List<String> getTodaysTweets(){
        List<String> tweets = new ArrayList<String>();

        tweets.add("Good Morning!");
        tweets.add("How are you??");
        return tweets;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do as below

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
listOfTweets = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1); 
// id of listview in activity_main.xml
TweetUtil tu = new TweetUtil();
List<String> list =tu.getTodaysTweets(); //get the list
tweetsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
listOfTweets.setAdapter(tweetsAdapter);
```

Comment: The code makes sense, and I just couldnt think like this. This was really useful. Thank you

Comment: I am getting error on this line,
tweetsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.simple.list_item_1,list);  
Error says simple.list_item_1 cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: @user3322635 use `android.R.simple_list_item_1`

Comment: yes I have used exactly the same line like you did, but they cant recognize it

Comment: @user3322635 update your code that should work abolutely no doubt about it

Comment: @user3322635 another mistake `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`. Sorry its a typo error

Comment: Thank you so much Raghunandan (Y) Now it worked. I just want to say that I made an another post two days ago. I didnt get a right solution for that till now. I really dont know why I got a layout like that. If you could look at it and see if you can give me a different tip, I will be really thankful :)) This is the post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22531776/the-layout-on-android-emulator-doesnt-look-like-the-layout-i-made-in-android-app?noredirect=1#comment34290232_22531776

Answer (score 0):

You can  broadcast here. When you get all tweets pass your arraylist to main class and fill you adapter.